# code change $args[‘readmore_text’] from to<?php _e( 'weiterlesen', 'meins' )

Tags: php, string, wordpress, translate

Have since a small module (wordpress) that does not automatically more language can.
Since WPML finds no string.

```
$html .= '<li class="weiterlesen"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="">' . $args['readmore_text'] . '</a></li></ul></div>';

replace . $args['readmore_text'] . to  <?php _e( 'readmore', 'tpl' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
$html .= '<li class="weiterlesen"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="">' . __( 'readmore', 'tpl' ) . '</a></li></ul></div>';
```